# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /Query.jsp at line 39

Tags: java, jsp

I have error when i try to put this line of code in my jsp file and run it.

```
<% DataCorrelationClient data= new DataCorrelationClient(); %>
```

or even a simple `<% string ="abc"%>`

will throw me an error.

i also have insert `<%@ page import="Webservice.DataCorrelationClient"%>` inorder for me to call my webservice using `httpcore-4.2.3` and `httpclient-4.2.3.jar` as a external jar to my project.

the error i got is: -

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /Query.jsp at line 39
```

anyone encounter this error before ? help ?

Comment: Look in your logs - they should show the details of the exception.

Comment: It should be there on default error page as well, copy the stacktrace here

Comment: <% string ="abc"%> is a compilation error, should be something like `<% String string ="abc";%>`, please paste the root cause in logs.

Answer (score 0):

Your *.jsp cannot be compiled because of the error in the scriptlet (variable string is not declared).

It looks like the container is trying to do it on request.

Compilation error is interpreted by the container as a runtime error the container intercepts it and sends you a page with the return code 500 ("Internal server error").

This is a standard how unhandled exceptions are treated.

---

Do not mark my answer as "answered", say thank you to @Subin.

He gave you the exactly right hint first.